# HBase request per second is zero

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I just created a table in HBase and filled it with data. From the 7 regionservers it appears the data was written to region servers 6 and 7.

But I dont understand why the requests per second is zero for servers 6 and 7?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Read request count* and *Write request count* are the total number of read and write requests seen by a particular region server since its restart. These numbers are kept in memory only for performance reasons and exposed via JMX and regionserver load API that the HBase UI uses to expose them. You could fetch them yourself using the API (or JMX) and export to a DB for persistence.

*Request per second* is the rate of total requests (read+write) that the regionserver in question is seeing **right now**. The rate is calculated based on the delta of the number of requests seen by that regionserver during a period divided by the length of the period. This particular detail (and this period) can differ based on HBase versions. In HBase 2.x, it is controlled by `hbase.regionserver.metrics.period`; while in previous versions there was no such setting and the period was fixed (if I remember correctly).

To answer your question, the comparison of rate of total requests and the count of total requests is not apples-to-apples. **The rate only reflects current traffic while the count reflects lifetime number of requests since region server's restart.**  If you really think about it, it does not make sense to have a rate of requests for lifetime, because any real use case is concerned with the current rate only.

Answer (score 0):

If you bulk-filled the tables via `put(List<Put>)`, there would only have been a very small number of requests, as records are sent in batches.

Comment: that makes sense.. but zero requests?

Comment: Presumably it was too low to appear.

Comment: @BenWatson The distinction you are talking about is between number of RPCs and number of operations. The HBase UI shows number of operations (read, write, total) and not the number of RPCs.